# SharePoint enterprise vs standard version

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

Can anyone describe what is the difference between the SharePoint 2013 Standard and Enterprise versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FPWeb, a SharePoint hoster (I am not affiliated to them nor working with them) has a nice edition comparision matrix here : http://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-hosting/2013/compare-sharepoint-server-standard-enterprise/

[image: standard vs enterprise]

It's in my opinion, at the time of writing (2012-12-15) one of the best and cleanest comparison matrix of the two edition.

Answer (score 1):

A matrix as far as I am aware hasn't been made, so an official comparison isn't easily available.

However combining:

[What's new in 2013 over 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607742%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

and

[SharePoint 2010 Editions Comparison](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/pages/editions-comparison.aspx)

You can get a rough idea.

Answer (score 1):

check the url entered below two know the comparison

http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/01/14/sharepoint-2013-feature-comparison-chart-all-editions/#SER

Comment: Please do not post link only answers

Answer (score 0):

We have Standard and off of the top of my head I recall two things that I have ran into: Standard lacks Excel Services and Business Data Connections (connections to systems external to Sharepoint).

Answer (score 0):

Here is very well comparison: [SharePoint 2013 – Foundation vs Standard vs Enterprise Server](http://www.apps4rent.com/sharepoint-2013-features-comparison.html)

Some other well links are:

- [SHAREPOINT 2013 STANDARD VS. ENTERPRISE VS. FOUNDATION FEATURE COMPARISON MATRIX](http://www.khamis.net/Blog/Post/275/SharePoint-2013-Standard-vs--Enterprise-vs--Foundation-Feature-Comparison-Matrix) , 2013 standard vs enterprise vs foundation
- [Overview of all SharePoint 2013 versions.](https://blog.blksthl.com/2013/01/14/sharepoint-2013-feature-comparison-chart-all-editions/#SIT)